# Python 3 List array

Tags: python, arrays, list, count

I run this code in Python 3.5 but i have an error when i run on python 2 not have  Error

```
import sys

class Array(object):
    def __init__(self, arr=[]):
        self.data = arr
    def salin(self):
        temp = Array(self.data)
        return temp
    def tambah(self, nilai):
        if self.data.count>0:
            if type(self.data[0])==type(nilai):
                self.data.append(nilai)
            else:
                print('Nilai yang ditambahkan harus sejenis')
                sys.exit(1)
    def ubah(self,indeks,nilai):
        self.data[indeks]=nilai
    def hapus(self,nilai):
        self.data.remove(nilai)
    def cari(self, nilai):
        return self.data.index(nilai)
    def urutkan(self):
        self.data.sort()
    def ekstrak(self,awal,akhir):
        temp = Array(self.data[awal:akhir])
        return temp
    def cetak(self):
        for nilai in self.data:
            print(nilai, end=' ')

        print()


def main():
    A = Array([10,20,30,40,50])

    #menampilkan nilai awal
    print('Isi A mula-mula: ',end=' ')
    A.cetak()

    #mengubah element ketiga
    A.ubah(2, 63)

    #menghapus nilai 40
    A.hapus(40)


    #menambah element
    A.tambah(70)
    A.tambah(15)

    #menampilkan isi nilai setelah diubah,
    #dihapus, dan ditambah
    print('Isi A setelah dimanipulasi: ',end=' ')
    A.cetak()

    B = A.ekstrak(1,4)
    print('Isi B (hasil Ekstrak): ', end='')
    B.cetak()

    C=A.salin()
    print('Isi C(salinan A): ',end='')
    C.cetak()

    C.tambah(45.25) # menabah nilai bertipe float

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: "i have an error" is not enough of a problem description to enable us to help you.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Please add the traceback

Comment: i run code `if self.data.count>0:
            if type(self.data[0])==type(nilai):
                self.data.append(nilai)
            else:` but that show the messege error `TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() > int()` on python 3

Comment: You probably want `if len(self.data)>0: ...`. The `count` method is used for counting the number of a particular item existing in the list; a callable attribute that takes one argument.

Comment: why that error on python 3 but not error on python 2

Comment: [Ordering comparisons](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons) changed in Python 3. A method and int can be ordered in Python 2, but not in Python 3

Comment: thks very much ffor u answr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`print` is not a function in Python 2. Syntactically, this isn't correct

```
print('message', end=' ')
```

If you want to use that `print` as a function in both Python 2 and 3, just import it

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

And replace `self.data.count` with `len(self.data)`

Comment: `if self.data.count>0:'

Comment: `TypeError: unorderable types: builtin_function_or_method() > int()`

Comment: I didn't try running the class. I tried running the code on both Python2 and 3, and that's the first error I saw